# How to Clean Up Ansible Runner Processes Stuck in Interaction?

Tags: ansible

I'm using ansible_runner to execute Ansible modules, typically the shell module. I have a scheduled script for running these tasks, but occasionally I encounter an issue: Ansible tasks seem to get stuck in some interaction, resulting in no response for a long period. When I check the system processes, I find these ansible processes still running. How can I effectively clean up these stuck processes?

I'm utilizing ansible_runner for executing tasks with the shell module.
This is being done within a cron job script.
When the issue occurs, the Ansible task appears to be waiting for interaction without any output.
These ansible processes are visible in the running state in the system process list.
I've tried to terminate these processes directly using the kill command on the Ansible control node, but I'm concerned this might leave orphan processes on the remote servers.

My questions are:

How can I safely and effectively clean up these stuck ansible processes?
Is there a way to prevent this situation, like setting a timeout or other mechanisms?
Any advice or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you check the timeout setting in ansible_runner?

Comment: "_typically the `shell` module. I have a scheduled script for running these tasks_", can you show some examples of them? "_in some interaction, resulting in no response for a long period. When I check the system processes, I find these ansible processes still running._", wouldn't it be helpful to find out what kind of content those processes are running what they are doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q: "*Is there a way to prevent this situation, like setting a timeout ...*"**

According the documentation [env/settings - Settings for Runner itself](https://ansible.readthedocs.io/projects/runner/en/stable/intro/#env-settings-settings-for-runner-itself)

- > *`idle_timeout`: `600` If no output is detected from ansible in this number of seconds the execution will be terminated.*
- > *`job_timeout`: `3600` The maximum amount of time to allow the job to run for, exceeding this and the execution will be terminated.*

**Q: "*... or other mechanisms?*"**

There is also an

> **5. 21 `Runner.cancel_callback`**
>
> *A function passed to `__init__` of **Runner**, and to the `ansible_runner.interface.run()` interface functions. This
> function will be called for every iteration of the `ansible_runner.interface.run()` event loop and should return
> `True` to inform **Runner** cancel and shutdown the **Ansible** process or `False` to allow it to continue.*

**Further Information**

- [Source code for `ansible_runner.runner`](https://ansible.readthedocs.io/projects/runner/en/stable/_modules/ansible_runner/runner/)
- [`ansible-runner` Documentation](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/stable/pdf/) PDF, p. 25-27, Example p. 27 ff.

---

Despite of that and regarding

> **"*... in some interaction, resulting in no response for a long period. When I check the system processes, I find these ansible processes still running.*"**

wouldn't it be helpful to find out what kind of content those processes are running what they are actually doing?

> **"*... typically the `shell` module. I have a scheduled script for running these tasks ..."*"**

examples of the script and the the commands given to the `shell` module would be helpful. As well how the "stuck" commands or processes behave usually and when executed in a SSH session.